# Red/blue shifting out of visible spectra

Tags: visible-light, doppler-effect

How fast would a white light (emitting only visible spectra) need to travel in order to red or blue shift so far its no longer visible?

Are some stars completely invisible due to this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you had a light source that was confined only to the visible spectrum, then a gamma of about 2 would do it: the human visual range is a hair less than 1 octave wide.

$$\begin{align*}
\gamma &= 2\\
\\
\left[ 1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2} \right]^{-1/2} & = 2\\
\\
\sqrt{1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2}} & = \frac{1}{2}\\
1 - \frac{v^2}{c^2} & = \frac{1}{4}\\
\frac{v^2}{c^2} & = \frac{3}{4}\\
v^2 & = \frac{3}{4}c^2\\
v &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}c
\end{align*}$$

Your follow-on asks about stars. The light from stars is roughly a black-body spectrum (of varying temperature, depending on the star) and is therefore not confined to the visible range, so the question is a more complicated one about how much there magnitude drops as a function of speed and that is also effected by Lorentz focusing.

Comment: Wow that's pretty quick (260,000 km/s approx), do any stars we know about have that kind of relative velocity? I get what you are saying about actual stars shifting their non-visible spectrum into visible.

Comment: @LukeMcGregor: The redshift of stars, or galaxies, in the Universe, comes from a related, but different effect. Galaxies don't move through space at particularly high speeds (typically a maximum of a few 100 or 1000 km/s). Rather, the galaxies lie roughly still in space, but space itself expands. That means that the most distant galaxies observed recede at roughly twice the speed of light. These galaxies are often detected by their emisson of ultraviolet light (Lyman α), which has redshifted _farther_ than visible and all the way to infrared wavelengths by the time we observe them.

Comment: …so the answer to the second part is that, yes, the fastest stars/galaxies redshift the part of their spectra that have the largest flux farther out than what is visible to the eye, but can still be observed in the IR. However, as dmckee says, the decline of flux is a more important reason that we can's see stars arbitrarily far away.